# saving a parent's relationship from child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, parent

I have the following relationship. I want a Post to has_one current_wrent but also has_many wrents that keeps tracks of wrent objects. I believe the issue may be related to rails being confused which relationship i'mr eferring to.

When I refer to a post.current_wrent, this is returning correctly with no errors.

```
Class Post

include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps
  ...
has_one :current_wrent, :class_name => "Wrent", :inverse_of => :current_wrent, :autosave => true, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :wrents, :inverse_of => :post, :dependent => :destroy
end

Class Wrent
..
belongs_to :post, :autosave => true
..
end
```

When I do something like..
  (in Wrent.rb)

```
def accept!
  update_attributes!(:status => 1, :accepted => true) 
  post.current_wrent = self
  post.available = false
  post.save!
  notify_user
end
```

and I get a "Current Wrent" is invalid error, could somebody point to me something I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: this seems to work fine.
in wrent.rb

```
Class Wrent
  ..
  belongs_to :post, :inverse_of => :wrent, :autosave => true
  belongs_to :post, :inverse_of => :current_wrent
```

in post.rb
    Class Post
      ...

```
  has_one :current_wrent, :class_name => "Wrent", :inverse_of => :post
  belongs_to :current_wrent, :class_name => "Wrent", :inverse_of => :post
  has_many :wrents, :inverse_of => :post, :dependent => :destroy
```

I'm still not sure what the problem is, but now I can access post.current_wrent through the belongs_to current_wrent_id column and the problem seemed to disappear.

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: I don't have a stack trace, but the last thing it does is post.save! and, which causes it to crash and return the error "Validation failed: Current_wrent is invalid". The issue has got to do with the way current_wrent relationship defined

Answer (score 1):

Your Wrent model probably has a post_id field where is stored the id of the Post that it belongs_to. But there's no field in Post to store the current_wrent.
Mongoid allows you to embed objects so what you can do is embeds_one instead has_one.

```
Class Post

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  ...
  embeds_one :current_wrent, :class_name => "Wrent", :inverse_of => :current_wrent
  has_many :wrents, :inverse_of => :post, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I don't want to keep it embedded - I can't delete, access or modify the wrent object arbitrarily unless I access the root document, which is what I don't want to do. I still want to be able to use the Wrent.find or Wrent.create and from my understanding, embedding it in a single object prevents it from being accessed elsewhere.

Comment: In that case you will need a belongs_to :current_wrent in Post class instead has_one to store the current_wrent object id.

Comment: Pretty much what I decided on. Thanks for your help!